# A/B testing multiple comparsion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

Following is the experimental design - There are two treatment group and one control. Need to conclude if treatment 1 is better than treatment 2. Is there a statistical test that helps in answering this question

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The test depends on what metric you want to measure. If it is website conversions you'd use a two sample test for proportions.
See this for [web experiments](http://www.exp-platform.com/Pages/hippo_long.aspx)

Comment: Here we need to do multiple comparison. T1 Vs C and T2 Vs C for this i can do individual t-test. how do I compare the difference between (T1Vs C) and (T2 Vs c) . Thanks

Comment: If it's a randomized trial you can directly compare t1 with t2. Why do you want to compare both with c and then take the difference?

Comment: Yes experiment is randomized. This information is helpful. I can compare T1 directly with T2. One question that is bothering me about - for this experiment design whether we need to use bonferroni correction.